# How to set a material table cell's background color conditionally

Tags: angular

in the example material table given [here,](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) if I want to change the background color of all cells that contain a value > 10, where would I put that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are so many ways to do it.
This is the one way to do it like in **weight** cell if value is greater than 10 then yellow color in background.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell [ngClass]="{clsWeight: element.weight > 10}" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

Here is the working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gm6cim?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-flex-example.html)

If you dont want to use **ngClass** then you can directly use the **style** like this

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell [style.background-color]="element.weight > 10 ? 'yellow' : ''" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

Working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qaqugn?file=src/app/table-basic-flex-example.html)